# HDFS Balancer - For cluster with 1KB files

Tags: hdfs

I have an HDFS cluster with 3 nodes. The cluster holds lots of small files (KB) and I have reached Millions of blocks per node.

I have added 4 more new servers to the cluster and started the balancer process but it looks that it does not do much. - The goal is to reduce the Million of blocks per server

In order to balance the small-size files should i change the value of the following parameter to support moving files from 1KB size?

Ddfs.balancer.getBlocks.min-block-size=1048

** I do know that HDFS should manage Big files  - working on compaction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are running a version with the dfs.balancer.getBlocks.min-block-size option, then the balancer will not move blocks below that size.

If you have a cluster with a mix of small and large files, the balancer picks blocks somewhat randomly. So if the majority of blocks are small, it will tend to move many more small blocks than large ones, and then the smaller blocks tend to build up on the nodes with less disk space used.

The above parameter was introduced to stop that happening.

Therefore if you need to get the small blocks to move, you will need to adjust that setting to something smaller than the default to get your blocks moving.